# not able to employ a neat javascript/jquery approach for the mobile menu system

Tags: javascript, mobile, dojo

I don't know if this is the right place to ask this , but please correct me if it ain't.
Now what i am having with me is a 
1)pair of navigational accordian with list items in them styled properly.
2)clicking on each list item will load an external page by ajax request.
Now what i actually want is when someone clicks on the list item, i want to call a handler function that makes some changes on some other page i have. Now i could do that by assigning id's to every list item and then setting up onclick listener, but that would be too time consuming and wont be neat.
Thats why i want to know if there is some approach i can try so that i can set up an onclick listener for all of them and which could identify which list item was clicked(as i have to make changes according to click on list item).

```
<div data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.Accordion">
    <div data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.RoundRectList" label="Intermediate">
        <div data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.ListItem"
            data-dojo-props="label:'Span and Div'" moveTo="spanView"></div>
        <div data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.ListItem"
            data-dojo-props="label:'Text'" moveTo="textView"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now This is something what i created for the menu, now using dojo i am making the ajax requests and now what i want to do is change contents of another third view based on the clicks of each of such list items.
Is there a neat javascript approach for this....
Please help.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could call the `getChildren()` method on your `dojox/mobile/RoundRectList` according to the [API documentation](https://dojotoolkit.org/api/dojox/mobile/RoundRectList). Then it will return each direct descendants (widgets), or in your case, the `dojox/mobile/ListItem`'s.

An example:

```
var items = registry.byId("list").getChildren();
array.forEach(items, function(item, idx) {
    item.onClick = function(evt) {
        console.log(this.label); 
    };
});
```

I also made a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g00glen00b/6p2Xk/) to demonstrate this.

Comment: ty for the answer, saved a lot of time